# drupal view how to find top one in all category

Tags: drupal, view

i have a content type event with following fields **date,type** and using fivestar module for voting. The type takes 3 possible values '*art', 'entertainment', 'iq'*. i try to generate a block that should display ***top event (by votes)*** in each category. any one have idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this relatively easy in a custom module, I have a hard time seeing how you would do this in views with the UI.

You need a query that looks something like this

```
SELECT nid FROM {voting_api} AS v
LEFT JOIN {content_content_type} AS c on v.content_id = c.nid
WHERE c.field_name = 'art'
AND v.function = 'count'
AND c.content_type = 'node'
ORDER BY v.value
LIMIT 1;
```

You need to run a query for each value, *art*, *entertainment* and *iq*. If you want to make it more reliable, you should use [`content_fields()`](http://api.lullabot.com/content_fields) and [`content_database_info()`](http://api.lullabot.com/content_database_info) to get the table name and column name of your CCK field (which can change over time).